# rm -rf: cannot remove `/opt/jetty': Directory not empty

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, directory, rm

I have a script using the following command to remove a folder:

```
ssh -q root@hostname sh -c 'rm -rf /opt/jetty/'
```

Most of the times it works fine, but occasionally I get this message:

> rm: cannot remove `/opt/jetty': Directory not empty

The only suspicious point is the folder to delete contains a lock file which is being used by shell command `flock` to acquire file lock. But I tried to remove the folder manually when the file was even being locked by `flock`, it get succeeded.

update:

---

The environment is Linux

```
# uname -a
Linux XXX 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 12:09:25 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

rm didn't alias to anything, the out put of rm:

```
# rm
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

I have a service script to start Jetty which creates a file lock inside the folder. Some snippet as shown below:

```
JETTY_LOCK=/opt/jetty/jetty_lock

start(){
    #open file descriptor and acquire lock
    exec 200>$JETTY_LOCK
    flock -x -n 200 || { exec 200>&-;echo 'jetty is being started by another process.'; sleep 5; exit 0; }
    ...
    cd /opt/jetty/
   ...
    echo $!>&200
    fi
    flock -u 200  #release lock
    exec 200>&-   #close file descriptor
}
```

update:

---

After the error reproduced, I found only jetty_lock file was still remaining int /opt/jetty, does that mean `flock` stops file lock from deleting? I cannot provide more details because I don't know when will it happen the next time...

Comment: Are new files commonly created in that directory?

Comment: hi @MichaelHomer, no new files except the lock file is created in that directory.

Comment: Is this on Linux? Which one? Is `rm` aliased to anything? What is the output of `type rm`? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: The other thing that you can tell people is whether you can reproduce this _when your [jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty/) service is not running_.  After all, jetty has a whole temporary files directory in `/opt/jetty/temp`, for starters.

Comment: If you change the command to `ssh -q root@hostname sh -c 'rm -rf /opt/jetty/ || ls -la /opt/jetty/'`, does it output anything?

Comment: Regardless of whether `/opt/jetty/` is empty or not, shouldn't the `rm -rf` command remove the directory without complaining? So is this issue really related to having contents in the directory or not?

Comment: @Sree The system calls used by rm cannot delete a non-empty directory. The -f option, per the standard, only omits diagnostic messages for arguments that do not exist. It's allowed to complain if the arguments exist and cannot be removed.

Answer (score -3):

To debug ssh session use "-v" option instead of "-q" and analize the output.

Try to use absolute paths in remote command. So this looks like:

```
# ssh -v root@hostname /bin/sh -c '/bin/rm -rf /opt/jetty/'
```

Comment: or use `ssh -vvv` for lots of detail

Comment: This question is a race between an `rm` command and a running [jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty/) service that is using/creating files and directories in the directory being removed.  It's not really addressed by looking at the SSH protocol or giving a different name for the shell.  Both of those are obviously working.

Comment: hi @JdeBP , do you mean the file lock cannot be removed by 'rm -rf'?

Comment: When you use sh instead of bash you have different alias. So you have to use absolute path. I don't know your environment, but /bin/rm -fr have to function. Are you sure remote filesystem is not in read-only mode?

Comment: hi @alex87alex I'm sure remote filesystem is not in read-only mode because all the files in the folder have been deleted except the one serves as file lock.